# Why does passing a javascript variable with the same name as a div Id pass the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think this is absolutely ludicrous.

**Given**

**HTML**

```
<div id = "statCounter"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var statCounter = 5;
```

**Executing**

```
console.log(statCounter);
// logs <div id = "statCounter"></div>
```

How can this be? How absurd is this?!!?
http://jsfiddle.net/rkkj58nw/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rkkj58nw/1/ ?

Comment: Perhaps in this simple script you're right, but in my more complicated app I am setting (example) statCounter to some object like, statCounter = { prop1 : 1, prop2 : 2};  I pass the statCounter but instead it passes the Div! I console.log(statCounter.prop2) and get 2! I console.log(statCounter) and get the div!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: Okay so I am not crazy.. I just have never seen this in my humble 2 years of dev and cannot believe it would be implemented like this in the first place.

Comment: In his book "Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja" John Resig calls this behavior of browser as "Greedy IDs". Look it up. When you cannot avoid [this](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/dont-name-inputs-action-submit/) has a workaround

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object

Answer (score 0):

This was a feature implemented in IE (presumably as a syntax sugar to avoid peppering your code with getElementById() in the long ago days before frameworks, I'm talking 1999).

Originally, other browsers such as Netscape didn't have this misfeature. But at some point some non-IE browsers started to implement this feature to be compatible with corporate websites that uses IE specific features.

I'm not entirely sure but I believe by now this is specified in some standard (either ECMAScript or HTML5 or something else). So now all browsers implement this "feature".

Comment: Note that this answer has a better explanation on the history of this bug than my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables?lq=1